# How to get sum and count in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, count, sum

[image]

I want to list Names, loan amount and number of loans that are Completed.

Thanks alot!!! Appreciate it.

Comment: can you include some sample input data?

Comment: included.. thanks..

Comment: is it total loan amount for all loans? or total per person? same question for Completed?  can you include expected response?

Comment: total amount is for all loans, same for total number of loans. I think there is only 1 unique person here in the data.. expected response would be: {Sam Yong, Guillermo Carlson, Bryan Swanson}, 234637106, 3. -- names, total loans completed, total number of loans completed.

Comment: is that possible? or I can only output the total loan amount and total count for completed per person?

Comment: sorry if its based on the data json script I sent, it should be {Yuyu Lee, Joseph Lee, Tan Meh Meh}, 2754816, 3

Comment: it's possible, posted an answer
this is a good reference for aggregation if you are from sql world: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/

Comment: do you only want names where the loan has status = 'Completed'?
and do you only want total to include where status = 'Completed'?

I removed the last 2 record in the mongo playground, there was an error with the data `error in configuration:
  invalid character '2' after object key:value pair`

Comment: or is it about the format or sorting? json arrays have `[]`

Comment: hi omg thanks so much.. your code works, but I actually only want names with loan status completed.. I tried inserting {$match:{"$status":"Completed"}} at the start before $group but it led to an error..

Comment: and yes im from sql world, just started learning mongodb, its really quite hard for me

Comment: I posted another answer, hopefully that's what you are looking for. mongodb querying does take some time to get used to. the sql-aggregation-comparison page helped me a lot when I was getting started with mongodb

Comment: wow thank you so much. you are really an expert! I have been trying this for almost an entire day... thanks alot, really appreciate it very much

Comment: lol :) I remember those days. It was really hard for me too when starting with mongodb. Keep practicing, one day it will just all make sense and you will like it.

Answer (score 0):

try:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/So-XDro3k2M

total_loan_amount = amount from all loans without check for status

all_names = all names without check for status

number_completed = total number of Completed loans

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      total_loan_amount: {
        $sum: "$loan_amount"
      },
      "all_names": {
        $push: "$name"
      },
      "statuses": {
        $push: "$status"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "all_names": 1,
      "total_loan_amount": 1,
      "number_completed": {
        "$size": "$statuses"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

response:

```
[
  {
    "all_names": [
      "John Tan",
      "Mary Lee",
      "Yuyu Lee",
      "Joseph Lee"
    ],
    "number_completed": 4,
    "total_loan_amount": 1.41132004e+08
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

try

https://mongoplayground.net/p/rA5T1PAxU9_

for results only from loans with Completed status

status isn't added to response, since it will always be 'Completed' from the input

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      status: "Completed"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      total_amount_from_completed_loans: {
        $sum: "$loan_amount"
      },
      "names_from_completed_loans": {
        $push: "$name"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

sample response:

```
[
  {
    "names_from_completed_loans": [
      "Yuyu Lee",
      "Joseph Lee"
    ],
    "total_amount_from_completed_loans": 1.836544e+06
  }
]
```